# How to add a space for user?

Tags: python

If i had a word that had space, like `abc def` for user to guess, and i want to input the space, so user don't have to guess the space.

Beacuse i had a code like this:

```
if len(letter)==1 and letter.isalpha():
            if letters_tried.find(letter) != -1:
```

Befor user gusee is:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

If guess the letter:

```
abc_def
```

is missing the space.

I want user only input alpha and i'll input the space for user. Is there away to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for next:

```
inputs = ["abc def", ...]
inputs_map = zip(inputs, [i.replace(' ', '') for i in inputs])

user_input = get_user_input()

user_input = inputs_map.get(user_input, user_input)
```